# Prove that if $T\alpha = c\alpha$ then there is basis for $range(T)$ that not linear dependent on $T\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing an exercise in Kunze Hoffman book and I'm stucked on a little point but I can't find any clue to finish the proof. So I hope someone here can help me to solve this. I'm really grateful for that.

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $F$ and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ . Let $c$ be a non-zero scalar
>   and suppose there is a non-zero vector $\alpha \in V$ such that $T\alpha = c\alpha$.
>   Suppose $\{T\alpha_{i}\}_{i=1}^{r}$ is basis of $range(T)$ with $\alpha = \alpha_{1}$. Extend the set $\{\alpha_{i}\}_{i=1}^{r}$ to become basis of $V$, $\{\alpha_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$. Prove that $T\alpha_{i}, i = 2,..., r$ can be expressed as linear combination of $\{\alpha_{i}\}_{i=2}^{n}$. On the other word, $T\alpha_{i}$ is independent of $\alpha$ in expression perspective to basis $\{\alpha_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$.

If you do not understand any point in the problem, please let me know. I'm not good at explaining the points. Moreover, please don't use characteristic value knowledge.It's out of my realm.
thanks so much.

Comment: The claim is false. Are you sure you have transcribed it correctly?

Comment: I got this claim in a proof of a professor. Can you give a counter-example to negate it? I think it's right...

Comment: I have eidted an index on the problem. You can review it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is still false, even with the edit.

For example, let $F=\Bbb{R}$, $V=\Bbb{R}^2$, and $T$ be the operator with matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ with respect to the standard basis. Then we can take $\alpha_1=\alpha=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0 \end{pmatrix}, a_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$, but $T\alpha_2$ is not a multiple of $\alpha_2$.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks so much for your help...